# How to check android mobile network mode setting state "Always on" or "Auto" or "Always off" programmatically?

Tags: android, wear-os, telephonymanager, android-settings, android-connectivitymanager

I need to get mobile network setting state in WearOS: "Always on" or "Auto" or "Always off".

**Exactly need to differentiate these states in code**

maybe there is a way through `ConnectivityManager` or `TelephonyManager` or `Settings.Secure`?

[image]

I've also checked that in system logs we have:

```
PhoneDataStore: putInt(mobile_networks_radio_power_key, 1) -> Always on
PhoneDataStore: putInt(mobile_networks_radio_power_key, 2) -> Always off
PhoneDataStore: putInt(mobile_networks_radio_power_key, 0) -> Auto

RadioModemPreference: onPreferenceClicked() key = RADIO_MODEM_ALLWAYS_ON
RadioModemPreference: onPreferenceClicked() key = RADIO_MODEM_ALLWAYS_OFF
RadioModemPreference: onPreferenceClicked() key = RADIO_MODEM_AUTO
```

Maybe there is a way to access PhoneDataStore from apps?

Answer (score 0):

```
Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver, "clockwork_cell_auto_setting") // OFF = 0; ON = 1
Settings.Global.getInt(contentResolver, "cell_on") // OFF = 0; ON = 1
```

|  | cell_on | clockwork_cell_auto_setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Always off | 0 | 0 |
| Always on | 1 | 0 |
| Auto | 1 or maybe? 0 | 1 |